# MySQL 5.1 import Excel file from LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, excel

I try to import a simple coma separated .txt file with the "LOAD DATA INFILE" function in my database table but I get this error message

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`;` LINES TERMINATED `\r\n`
```

Here is my LOAD DATA function :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/IMPORT/donnees.txt' INTO TABLE titres_csc FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Here is the coma separator txt file :

> ID_Titre;Num_Lot_CSC;Date_Lot_CSC;Num_Client;Type_Titre;Num_Carnet;Num_Titre;Mt_Titre;Num_Adresse_Livraison;Millesime;Type_Carnet;Service;Num_Cde_Client;Date_Cde_Client;Intitulé_1;intitulé_2;Nom_contact_1;Nom_contact_2;Lig_Adr1;Lig_Adr2;Lig_Adr3;Lig_Adr4;Lig_Adr5;Zone_Geo;Type_anomalie;Code_anomalie;Date_Fab;Num_colis;Date_Liv;Utilisateur;Num_imprimante1;Num_imprimante2
>   1;12556613;20131209;123456789;Repas;1;1;1400;;2014;20;ressource humaine;1234567890123;;Gie Chèques Services Calédoniens;98 800 NOUMEA;Florence MARAYE;Jacques MERCADAL;14, rue des cerises;Magenta;98 800 NOUMEA;;;Noumea;;;;;;;;
>   2;12556613;20131209;123456790;Repas;1;2;1400;;2014;20;ressource humaine;1234567890123;;Gie Chèques Services Calédoniens;98 800 NOUMEA;Florence MARAYE;Jacques MERCADAL;14, rue des cerises;Magenta;98 800 NOUMEA;;;Noumea;;;;;;;;
>   3;12556613;20131209;123456790;Repas;1;3;1400;;2014;20;ressource humaine;1234567890123;;Gie Chèques Services Calédoniens;98 800 NOUMEA;Florence MARAYE;Jacques MERCADAL;14, rue des cerises;Magenta;98 800 NOUMEA;;;Noumea;;;;;;;;

It seems to be the FIELDS TERMINATED BY function that is not working, but refering the MySQL documentation, this code is correct.

Thanks for your help guys !

Comment: UTF-8 problem with the french characters? Maybe quoting helps.